# Trying to create a templated linked list that contains different types of data

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

Hey i'm trying to create a linked list and i've ran into a dead end.
I think my knowledge about templates is leaving me at a blank!

so i'm trying to create a linked list that contains an **object**, which contains a **reference to some data** and a **reference to the previous object** in the list.

so something like this:

```
template<class T>
class ClassHeader
{
    //-- Variables
    T* object;
    ClassHeader<T>* previousHeader;
};
```

I'm imagining it like this:

```
     Data______       Data_____
    |          |     |         |
    |__________|     |_________|
     ^                ^
     |                |
     |   Header       |   Header
    |Data*     |     |Data*    |
<---|Header*   |<----|Header*  |
    |          |     |         |
    |__________|     |_________|
```

And i'll be keeping a reference to the 'top' classheader of the list somewhere else. And then i plan on going down the list and accessing each 'object' as i go.

I can't figure out how to do this so far, as i would (as far as i can tell) need to know the the type of each previous 'object' before hand which is the information i'm trying to get!

Also each 'object' reference (data in the diagram) can be a completely different type.

Any help?

Comment: Why does it need to contain a pointer to the object? Why not just place an instance of the class inside the linked list class itself? Generally linked lists are composed of Nodes which contain the data type of the list and a pointer to the next element in the list.

Comment: Maybe ditch the templating and use [inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6118721/395718). Or, if inheritance is impossible, use your own VARIANT that can hold all the types you care about.

Comment: @Stephen Even if it did contain the instance would that not still have the same problem? as i'd still need to know the type of the previous header to initiliase the *previousHeader, right?

Comment: So wait, each link in the list can have a different data type? It isn't a single homegenous type contained in the whole list?

Comment: @Stephen Yeah, i mentioned in the post that each object reference can be a different type. So each link will be a 'ClassHeader' but with a reference to any possible object. So if I make a class Foo i can pass its reference to a new Classheader and it will now contain a reference to Foo and a reference to the previous ClassHeader.

Comment: The problem I see is that you wouldn't be able to define pointers to these objects because you would need to know the template type in order to create a pointer to that type.

Comment: @Stephen Yeah, tha's why i needed help, i wanted to know if it was possible to do this? to create this kind of list?

Comment: Does the list have to be able to hold any type or just the base types like int, float, double?

Comment: XY problem. Why do you need such a list? What would you do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this pattern from "[Inheritance is the base class of evil](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil)" talk will help...

Corresponding source code can be found here - https://github.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2012/blob/master/fri/value_semantics/value_semantics.cpp

Just take classes object_t and model_t from the code above and make object_t - the data type of your list. define helper and access methods as needed.

Comment: The only problem is that the data in my list has to be able to be **anything** that's where i'm hitting the problem. So i need to be able to make a class (any class whatsoever) and pass a pointer to it to the classHeader which will contains its pointer for its lifetime.

Comment: Luke,

This is exactly what object_t does. It has a templated constructor that can take any type as parameter. Internally this results in creation of another templated descendant of model_t.

Comment: okay, i think maybe i read over it a little too quickly but maybe, possibly this is what i'm looking for :) i'll have a proper look at it and see if there's any way i can use this. Thanks!